# How to get YouTube autoplay to work for website?

Tags: html, youtube, autoplay

I've been trying to get a youtube video to autoplay for clients when they go to my website.
I've been looking around and I see that Google disabled that feature. Is there anyway to code something so people don't have to enable it manually, or click on it manually? 
I'm no coding pro so please pardon my ignorance

My code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DkW87-Z9FAY?autoplay=1"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also if this can't be fixed, how can I center an iframe vertically and horizontally. I'm trying to do it like an image but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `autoplay=autoplay`gives you a somewhat friendlier initial frame, but it won't autoplay.  If you download the video and serve it from your end, you can try using the HTML5 autoplay attribute of the `video` tag.  Autoplay is considered bad practice anyway per the MDN documentation, so maybe you've already got what you need here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: Ah okay, I'll keep it off then. Do you know how to vertically and horizontally align?

Comment: Yes, but that's a separate question.  Also, questions about centering are all over SO and very well documented.  You probably don't need to ask a new question about it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you set, because browsers and users have their own preferences already set.